# On scrolling, header opacity changes but on stop scrolling it comes back to 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, basically, I have an header on my webpage and when I'm scrolling, I want this header to become transparent (opacity 0.4) and when I stop scrolling, it comes back up (opacity 1).

Comment: A little more info would be good.  What have you tried?

Comment: @MadSkunk I tried to paste the code into the head section with <script type="text/javascript"> and then change the name #header to #cabecalho (its header in portuguese) but the header still doesnt fade.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    $(document.body).on("scroll", function(){
        $("#header").fadeTo("fast", 0.4);
        if(timer)
            clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#header").fadeTo("fast", 1);
        }, 100);
    });
};
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this but nothing happens, I'm kinda newbie so maybe I set the code wrong. The header div is <div id="cabecalho"> and I pasted the code in the <head> section (I suppose its in there) with: <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
    var timer;
    $(document.body).on("scroll", function(){
        $("#cabecalho").css("opacity", "0.4");
        if(timer)
            clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $("#cabecalho").css("opacity", "1");
        }, 50);
    });
} and nothing happened, the header still doesn't fade.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is then, I changed the call to use fadeTo and have a longer timeout, but that should work.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work either. Well, the header has other divs with text, and there is no background. Is it something related to that?

Answer (score 0):

Setting timeout is the best to solution to catch the user stop scrolling. You need also to set a `stop()` to prevent further fading and flickering.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
    $("#header").stop().fadeTo("fast", 0.4);

    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timeout'));
    $.data(this, 'timeout', setTimeout(function() {
        $("#header").stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);
    }, 300));

});
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/daec2/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work. My header div has no background, it only has text.

Comment: When setting opacity on an element it will also affect the texts, see this [jsfiddle.net/daec2/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/daec2/1/). I think you better need to check if things are being fired on scroll, debug with a console.log or alert.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm too noob for that console.log thingy. How can I show you that?